# python readlines() does not contain whole file

Tags: python, python-2.7, readlines

I have an auto-generated info file coming from a measurement. It consists of both binary as well as human readable parts. I want to extract some of the non binary meta data. For some files, I am not able to get to the meta data, as the `readlines()` does not yield the whole file. I guess that the file contains some EOF char. I can open the file in notepad++ without problems.

A possible solution to this problem would be to read in the file binary and parse it to char afterwards, deleting the EOF char while doing so. Anyhow, I wonder if there is a more elegant way to do so?

Edit:
The question was rightfully downvoted, I should have provided code. I actually use

```
f = open(fname, 'r')
raw = f.readlines()
```

and then proceed with walking through the list. The EOF chars that are existing (depending on the OS) seem to cause the havoc I am observing. I will accept the answer that states using the binary `'rb'` flag. By the way, this was an impressive response time! (-:

Comment: Can you show us your code? Have you accessed the file in any other way? How was the file object opened?

Comment: Why do you mixing binary and human-readable parts? Did you open the file in binary or in just "r" format?

Comment: There is nothing like EOF char.

Comment: @Messa there is an EOF marker \x1A if I remember correctly... This is why when using files whereby said character can occur, it's always best to force binary so they're not interpreted as such (especially on Windows anyway)

Comment: @JonClements That's just a character like the 255 other ones. https://gist.github.com/messa/90c7c24120693dee2af7

Comment: Is the metadata contained in specific sections of the file?

Comment: @JonClements: Even Windows won't stop reading the file if it encounters `\x1A` in a text-mode file. You'd almost think so, but there is no way to 'null terminate' a file like that.

Comment: @Martijn might well be different circumstances I'm thinking of then :P)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
with open(afile,"rb") as f: print f.readlines()
```

What's the problem with doing this?

If you don't open the file in binary mode some non ASCII characters are incorrectly interpreted and or discarded... Which may inadvertently also remove some ASCII if it is mixed in with binary data

Comment: *If you don't open the file in binary mode all non ASCII characters are discarded...* - errr - no... if it's not opened in binary modes, some characters still having meanings such as "This is the end of the file"

Comment: I just tried this code, setting the binary flag like this actually does the trick for me. In the list I can then look for the keywords I am searching! No `struct` needed.

Comment: Yeah your right @jonclements ... Still not sure why I got down voted for this...it's hard to answer SO questions on my phone

Comment: @Joran no idea either - definitely was not me mate

Comment: yeah I assumed it wasn't you actually... just not sure who it was or more importantly why

Comment: Had the same problem as OP had. Adding "rb" to opening mode solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `read()` function of the file object. It reads the whole file.

```
with open('input.bin', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()
```

Then you can parse the content.
If you know where the part you need starts, you can seek to it (e.g. if the file has a fixed-length binary start):

```
with open('input.bin', 'r') as f:
    f.seek(CONTENT_START)
    content = f.read()
```

On Windows, you should change the reading mode to 'rb', to indicate that you want to read the file in binary mode; only then line endings in the text-part may consist of '\r\n', depending on how you created the file in the first place.

Comment: I thought of that, but sadly, the binary is not same size for all files.

Comment: @Faultier: You can use this solution without the f.seek(...) part then. This approach won't have the problem you mention, f.read() reads the whole file. On Windows, it may be worth changing the reading mode to 'rb' to indicate that you want to read the file in binary mode.